# Web scraping multiple pages when the url changes and adds 'offset=[# here]'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get('https://reelgood.com/source/netflix')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find_all('tr',attrs={'class':'cM'})

records = []
for t in title:
    movie = t.find(attrs={'class':'cI'}).text
    year = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').text
    rating = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').findNext('td').text
    score = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').text
    rottenTomatoe = t.find(attrs={'class':'cJ'}).findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').text
    episodes = t.find(attrs={'class':'c0'}).text[:3]
    records.append([movie, year, rating, score, rottenTomatoe, episodes])

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['movie', 'year', 'rating', 'score', 'rottenTomatoe', 'episodes'])
```

The code above gets me 49 records, which is the first page. There are 43 pages i want to scrape. Every time you go to the next page to get the next 50 videos the url initially from the first page to the second adds "?offset=150" and then every page after it increases by 100. Here is an example of what the url looks like for the last page (as you can see the offset=4250) "https://reelgood.com/source/netflix?offset=4250"

any help on how to get a result set of all the pages would be very helpful. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would be just grabbing the class='eH' where the link for more content resides.

It's the only class on the page that has that value. And when you reach offset=4250 the link is gone.

So the loop would be like this:

```
records = []
keep_looping = True
url = "https://reelgood.com/source/netflix"
while keep_looping:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    # grab your content here and store it and find the next link to visit.
    title = soup.find....
    for t in title:
        ....
        records.append...
    # if the tag does not exist, url will be None
    # we will then tell the while-loop to stop by setting the keep_looping flag to False"
    url_tag = soup.find('a', class_='eH')
    # returns not absolute urls but "/source/netflix?offset=150"
    if not url_tag:
        keep_looping = False
    else:
        url = "https://www.reelgood.com" + url_tag.get('href')
df = pd.DataFrame...
```

Comment: would it be something like this? but instead of the t in title i would replace that to look at soup?

Comment: if you dont mind me asking how did you find the "url_tag" class "eH"?

Answer (score 1):

I work at Reelgood. Please note that the class names on https://reelgood.com change every-time we release a update to our web app.

We are more than happy to lend a hand with whatever you're trying to accomplish here, feel free to shoot me an email at luigi@reelgood.com.